# Плавное изменение высоты блока при клике

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation

```js
$(function(){
  $(".buttonupdown").click(function(){ 
      $(".droplist").toggleClass('active')
      $(".buttonicon").toggleClass('active')  
    });
  });
```

```css
.droplist {
        
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 80px 70px -70px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 30px 15px 50px 15px;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    .buttonupdown {
        
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        background: #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0 auto;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        
        
    }
    
    
    .droplist.active {
        

        height: 100%;
        transition: all 0.3s;

        
        
    }
    
    .buttonupdown:hover {
        
        cursor: pointer;
        
    }
        
    
    .buttonicon {
        
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        opacity: 0.1;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    
    .buttonupdown:hover .buttonicon {
        
        opacity: 0.9;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        
    }
    
    
    .buttonicon.active {
        
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    .fogunderbutton {
        
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="droplist">

    
    <ul style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; margin-left: 0px;">
    
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
        <li>текст</li>
    </ul>
    
    
    <div class="fogunderbutton"></div>
<div class="buttonupdown">
    <div style="height: 7.5px;"></div>
    <div class="buttonicon">
    
    
        <svg color="#787878" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M509.121,125.966c-3.838-3.838-10.055-3.838-13.893,0L256.005,365.194L16.771,125.966c-3.838-3.838-10.055-3.838-13.893,0    c-3.838,3.838-3.838,10.055,0,13.893l246.18,246.175c1.842,1.842,4.337,2.878,6.947,2.878c2.61,0,5.104-1.036,6.946-2.878    l246.17-246.175C512.959,136.021,512.959,129.804,509.121,125.966z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
    
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: а где, собственно, сам скрипт который нужно подправить? И как мне кажется тебе просто нужно добавить `transition` к действию

Comment: Я не очень специалист в этом) код вставлял, но он почему то показывается с ошибкой  
transition не работает почемуто


$(function(){
  $(".buttonupdown").click(function(){ 
      $(".droplist").toggleClass('active')
      $(".buttonicon").toggleClass('active')  
    });
  });

Comment: добавь этот код в вопрос что бы люди могли видеть как что работает

Comment: height 100% не анимируется, используйте max-heght

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```js
$(function() {
  $(".buttonupdown").click(function() {
    $(".droplist").toggleClass('active')
    $(".buttonicon").toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
.droplist {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 80px 70px -70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px 15px 50px 15px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

.buttonupdown {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.droplist.active {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.buttonupdown:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonicon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.buttonupdown:hover .buttonicon {
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.buttonicon.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.fogunderbutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="droplist">


  <ul style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; margin-left: 0px;">

    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
  </ul>


  <div class="fogunderbutton"></div>
  <div class="buttonupdown">
    <div style="height: 7.5px;"></div>
    <div class="buttonicon">


      <svg color="#787878" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M509.121,125.966c-3.838-3.838-10.055-3.838-13.893,0L256.005,365.194L16.771,125.966c-3.838-3.838-10.055-3.838-13.893,0    c-3.838,3.838-3.838,10.055,0,13.893l246.18,246.175c1.842,1.842,4.337,2.878,6.947,2.878c2.61,0,5.104-1.036,6.946-2.878    l246.17-246.175C512.959,136.021,512.959,129.804,509.121,125.966z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>


    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
 $(function(){
  $(".buttonupdown").click(function(){ 
      $(".droplist").slideToggle();
      $(".buttonicon").toggleClass('active'); 
    });
  });
```